# Unifying a lot of scalar arrays

Tags: php, arrays

Is there any more efficient way for unifying a lot of scalar arrays?

```
<?php

$input=[
    [65455,5,5,4,1,4,45,4],
    [2,1254,5,454,54,545,4],
    //....
];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cut it down with a trick:

```
 array_unique(call_user_func_array("array_merge", $input))
```

By using [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/call_user_func_array) the `array_merge` will be run implicitly with each row of your input array as parameter: `array_merge($input[0], $input[1], $input[2], ...)`

Though that's one of those occassions where comments are imperative to make up for terseness.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement correctly, you're looking for [`array_merge`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php).

Answer (score 0):

```
function array_union($arrayOfArrays){
    $output=[];
    foreach ($arrayOfArrays as $a) {
       $output=array_unique(array_merge($output,$a));
    }
    return $output;
}
```